# Python Gtk.Treeview Enter key

Tags: gtk

I am trying to detect the Enter key being pressed on an item in a Treeview.
The aim is to open a dialogue box for editing the line. I have been searching for days. The "changed" item is not suitable as it is activated by moving onto the item in the list, and not the Enter Key.
All the other attempts (Found from the net) generate various errors.
I am new to Gtk and maybe this is the wrong approach?`enter code here`

```
        selected_row = tasks_tree_view.get_selection()
        selected_row.connect("changed", self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect("activate", self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect("pressed", self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect("clicked", self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect(onButtonPressed, self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect("event", self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect("key-press-event", self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect("row-activated", self.item_selected)
#        selected_row.connect("cursor-changed", self.item_selected)
```

Comment: I believe the `key-press-event` would be the one you want.

Comment: No, connect to `row-activated` on the tree view itself, not on the tree selection object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the [`row-activated` signal of the **GtkTreeView** object](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-row-activated). Your approaches are failing because you are trying to connect to the **GtkTreeSelection** object. So in your case, you want

```
tasks_tree_view.connect("row-activated", self.item_activated)
```

(Mind the signal parameters. I don't know what they are in Python; sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

I combined both of your answers to get

`tasks_tree_view.connect("key-pressed", self.item_activated)`

And this solved my problem.

Many thanks to you both.